# Risk of data loss after turning on iCloud photos, before initial sync completes?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

I have 450GB of photos on my iPhone. iCloud photos was turned off until recently so my iPhone backup was taking up about 500GB of space on iCloud.

Upon turning on iCloud photos, my iCloud storage usage instantly went down to about 50GB, i.e. the backup only takes up 50GB, as it no longer includes photos.

Although this makes sense (no need to duplicate photos in the cloud in both the backup and iCloud photos), the initial photos sync to iCloud is very, very slow and seems like it may take a week to complete. Currently only 5% of my photos are synced to iCloud Photos. The progress bar is displayed at the bottom of the Recents album. Syncing only occurs when on wifi and plugged in.

Does this mean, if my phone dies on me today, and I later restore to a new phone from iCloud backup, I will lose 95% of my photos?

- iPhone: 12 Pro Max 512GB
- iOS version: 14.8

Comment: So plug phone into Mac, run Image Capture, copy all photos from phone.  Should have made a local backup of the phone before turning on iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: re restoring an iCloud backup to the phone... since your photos are no longer participating in backups, if you nuke the phone and restore the backup that does not contain them, you no longer have **any** photos.  You are then dependent on whatever is in iCloud syncing back to the phone to have any content.